# What is wrong with my sorting logic?

Tags: php, sort

Trying to sort a custom query. I need the values to be sorted based on the menu order. The following code prints out all the values as expected, but not in any sorted order. I'm trying to get the integer values sorted

```
    foreach ($questions as $question){
    $values = array ( get_post($question->ID)->menu_order );
    sort($values);
    foreach($values as $value){
        echo '<br>' . $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're sorting each value individually, because that logic is inside your $questions loop. You need to make an array containing all of the IDs and then sort that afterwards.

Comment: That said, can't you get the database to do the sort by adding an order to the query?

Comment: Actually, just sorting the $questions gets the desired effect - however the issue is that there are repeat menu_orders (for example, menu order 1 has 3 items, menu order 2 has 6 items, menu order 3 has 3 items, etc) - but the thing I'm going for is only ONE menu order (at random) is to get selected, while still being sorted by menu_order if that makes sense

Comment: For example - this sorting works:

sort($questions);
 foreach ($questions as $question){
  echo get_field('text', $question->ID);
  echo get_post($question->ID)->menu_order;
 }

- but how can I ensure that if a menu_order appears once, it can no longer appear in the list?